# WebMvcConfigurer and Jackson postprocessing

Tags: java, servlets, jackson

Consider a controller which returns urls with protocol and domain:

```
GET /test
{"url": "https://example.com/foo/bar"}
```

I would like to implement a filter or modification to Jackson which would postprocess such responses and remove the protocol and domain based on a parameter:

```
GET /test?clearDomain=true
{"url": "/foo/bar"}
```

I tried via Filters, but I got stuck in cycles with `getWriter() has already been called for this response` - I don't think that is going to work for all cases.

The way could probably be via Jackson postprocessing:

```kotlin
class WebConfigurer : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun extendMessageConverters(converters: MutableList<HttpMessageConverter<*>>) {
        // configureMessageConverters will leave out the default ones which are necessary
        val originalList = ArrayList(converters)

        converters.forEach {
            if (it is MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                it.objectMapper // TODO postprocess somehow here
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two issues:

1. Jackson is not aware of HttpServletRequest, so it cannot get hold of `clearDomain` parameter.
2. I can't find a way to tell Jackson to do something in the end of the response.

Comment: Did you try to create custom serializer for that class?

Comment: `Jackson` is the best for serializing and should be used only for that. In case the view should be modified we could use annotations, mixins or custom serializers. In this case you want to implement business logic, get data from `HTTP` request and do something with that. I would suggest to implement extra layer which would transform data into right **form** and pass this transformed object to serialization process. It would pay off when you start implementing more sophisticated logic. Unit tests also would be much easier to implement.